# URL detection and linking in arbitrary text

Tags: regex, url

So [Gruber's regex](http://daringfireball.net/2010/07/improved_regex_for_matching_urls) is fantastic for finding URLs inside text. What I'm missing is some way to turn casual-style links like `bit.ly/foo` into things that can go in an `<a href="...">` property.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes the simplest answer is the right one:

```
function canonicalise(url) {
  if (!url.match(/^[a-z][\w-]+:/i)) {
    url = 'http://' + url
  }
  return url
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one: `([a-z0-9_-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,4}/[^ ]*` Consists of:

- At least one time a host or domain name (containing alphanumeric chars underscore and dash)
- then a TLD which is at least 2 and at most 4 characters long and contains only letters
- then a slash character
- followed by zero or any number non-space characters

This is not very restrictive, but probably does the job for message boards and such.

Comment: I already have a URL matching regex. I want a canonical way to turn `'bit.ly/foo'` into `'http://bit.ly/foo'`, but have e.g. `'mailto:foo@bar.com'` stay as `'mailto:foo@bar.com'`.

Comment: This thing does just that. Note that you got to have a slash character which is true for `bit.ly/foo` but leaves `mailto:foo@bar.com` intact.

Comment: Because you didn't answer the question. I *already have* a regex for matching URLs.

Comment: I gave you a RegEx which will identify the string `bit.ly/foo` but NOT  `mailto:foo@bar.com`. This is what you said in your comment. Regedless what you *already have* is obviously not doing this the way you want, so why does it matter that you aready have a RegEx which does not work? This one works and identifies the *casual* URL's just what you asked for. Of course it does not do **substitution**, you didn't give any languages (not even in the form of tags), but prepending a `http://` string sould not be a problem in any language.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
/((?<=[^a-zA-Z0-9])(?:https?\:\/\/|[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,}\.{1}|\b)(?:\w{1,}\.{1}){1,5}(?:com|org|edu|gov|uk|net|ca|de|jp|fr|au|us|ru|ch|it|nl|se|no|es|mil|iq|io|ac|ly|sm){1}(?:\/[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,})*)/mg
```

https://regex101.com/r/fO6mX3/2